# query about glib c setmntent function

Tags: c, glibc, mount

I have seen something like

```
setmntent(MOUNTED, "r");
```

What is the significance of `MOUNTED`? Is it a keyword? Macro?

After reading the man page of `setmntent`, I was of the opinion that the first argument to `setmntent`is `file*` which could be `/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts`. But this `MOUNTED` word has confused me.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are Macros in [mmtent.h](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/mntent_002eh.html).

```
/* File listing canonical interesting mount points.  */
#define MNTTAB      _PATH_MNTTAB    /* Deprecated alias.  */

/* File listing currently active mount points.  */
#define MOUNTED     _PATH_MOUNTED   /* Deprecated alias.  */
```

> Defines the type struct mntent and the macros MNTTAB, MOUNTED, MNTTYPE_*, MNTOPT_*, and 
>   declares the functions setmntent, getmntent, getmntent_r, addmntent, endmntent, hasmntopt.

The macros FSTAB, MNTTAB, and MOUNTED define a Path, but they are an deprecated alias and `_PATH_MNTTAB`  and `_PATH_MOUNTED` should be used.

`#define    _PATH_FSTAB "/etc/fstab"` (fstab.h)

`#define _PATH_MOUNTED      "/etc/mtab"` (ie. [paths.h](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/generic/paths.h;h=03bf0f355f693b8ed6f8fc5272c74b802d1f30df;hb=b4c4f7767d22b1e2ddbb3f0657418acafa323017) of glibc)

see [Mount-Information](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mount-Information.html).

Answer (score 0):

`setmntent()`'s first paramter is `char *`, referring to a "string", the name of a file containing a file system description.

For the code snippet you provided I can just guess that `MOUNTED` might be defined like

1

```
#define MOUNTED "/etc/mtab"
```

or 2

```
char MOUNTED[] = "/etc/mtab"
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/mntent_002eh.html:

> **`mntent.h`**
>
> Defines the type struct mntent and the macros `MNTTAB`, `MOUNTED`, `MNTTYPE_*`, `MNTOPT_*`...

Note that `setmntent` takes a file path as the first argument, so `MOUNTED` is defined as a file path, [usually](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/include/paths.h) `"/etc/mtab"` (if the macro is even available).